# How to convert an image string into integer on Android?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-maps-markers, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I want to retrieve an image from Firebase and place it in a canvas so that I use it to place in the custom google marker. I get an error when I use the **.toInt()** method. Maybe that's a wrong way of doing it.

The code:

```
var loggedInUser : User = User()

                            mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
                                    .document(FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserId())
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                                        loggedInUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!
                                    }
                            canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,loggedInUser.image.toInt()), 0F, 0F, color)
                            canvas1.drawText("User Name!", 30F, 40F, color)




                            // add marker to Map

                            // add marker to Map
                            markerOptions
                                    .position(LatLng(mLastLocation!!.latitude, mLastLocation!!.longitude))
                                    .title("Current Location")
                                    /*.snippet(address)*/
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))

                            mCurrentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
```

The logcat where I get error:

```
2021-07-06 19:33:54.839 10676-10676/com.example.aroundyouapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.aroundyouapp, PID: 10676
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
    at com.example.aroundyouapp.activities.MainActivity$getCurrentLocation$1.onLocationResult(MainActivity.kt:394)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzau.notifyListener(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ListenerHolder.notifyListenerInternal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:17)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ListenerHolder$zaa.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:6)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zar.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:8)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

How can I convert the Image that is in string format(i.e, **loggedInUser.image**) to Int so that the image is placed on the canvas? Maybe this is a stupid question but I'm new to this so yeah.

Thank you in advance

**Edit 1:**

The code that I use to display the profile picture of the user in the navigation menu:

```
fun loadUserData(activity: Activity){
    //This function is called in MainActivity in the onCreate method.
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(getCurrentUserId())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val loggedInUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)

            when(activity){
                is MyProfileActivity -> {
                    activity.setUserDataInUI(loggedInUser!!)
                }
                is MainActivity -> {
                    activity.updateNavigationUserDetails(loggedInUser!!)
                }
            }
        }
}

fun updateNavigationUserDetails(user: User){
    hideProgressDialog()
    mUserName = user.name
    Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(user.image)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_place_holder)
            .into(nav_user_image)

    tv_username.text = user.name
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I tried Ragu's answer. The app crashed after trying it.

This is the error in the logcat.

```
2021-07-14 19:07:04.779 18663-18663/com.example.aroundyouapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.aroundyouapp, PID: 18663
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aroundyou-5f1d2.appspot.com/o/USER_IMAGE1624282533208.jpg?alt=media&token=731ea81d-32a0-4378-aa7b-0d7764260e41"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
    at com.example.aroundyouapp.activities.MainActivity$getCurrentLocation$1$onLocationResult$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:374)
    at com.example.aroundyouapp.activities.MainActivity$getCurrentLocation$1$onLocationResult$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:349)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I got the same error last time but this time the link of the image is shown in the logcat

**Edit 3**

Got this error after trying updated answer 2 by Ragu

```
2021-07-14 20:05:57.399 20234-20234/com.example.aroundyouapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.aroundyouapp, PID: 20234
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.example.aroundyouapp.activities.MainActivity$getCurrentLocation$1$onLocationResult$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:379)
    at com.example.aroundyouapp.activities.MainActivity$getCurrentLocation$1$onLocationResult$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:352)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Please remove .toInt() from loggedInUser.image.toInt()

Comment: If I don't add that then it says "Required: Int, Found: String". Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Just check for empty string in this case.. 
if ( loggedInUser.image.toString(),length() > 0) {
canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,loggedInUser.image.toInt()), 0F, 0F, color)
}

Comment: Now there is no marker shown lol

Comment: I think the image in string format is in a certain manner? and maybe we can't just convert it into Int and make it work i guess?

Comment: Ok so first of all check if any data is coming in loggedInUser from the firestore. Debug or use a log to check. Then we move onto the next step

Comment: oh wow. i used log and apparently **loggedinuser.image** is empty because the log didn't print anything. It's strange because the user has a profile photo and i use the same method to load profile photo of the user in the navigation menu and it works there but not here. why?

Comment: Maybe you must be missing something. Can you share the code?

Comment: `if(loggedInUser.image.isNotEmpty()){
                                    Log.e("Image detected", "Image Detected")
                                    canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,loggedInUser.image.toInt()), 0F, 0F, color)
                                }` 
Is this the code you wanted?

Comment: No not this. Above you said that you used the same code to display picture in the navigation menu and not working here. So share that code which you are using there to display the picture.

Comment: Updated the question. Please check it out. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234658/discussion-between-perpetualdarkness-and-hascher).

Comment: Your string is empty (from your log `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`), so you cannot call toInt.

Comment: How can i load the photo? is there any way to do it? The firebase has a profile picture. The photo in navigation menu gets loaded tho

Comment: `loggedInUser.image` is base64 string format or something else ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan I'm not sure. I did some research before asking this question and apparently the string must be in base64 string format and I also searched how I can do that in Kotlin but I didn't really find any source for that. Can you help me w/ this

Comment: Yes. I can help you. It will be helpful if the format of the `loggerInUser.image` is included in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume you are trying to display the image which is in `Base64` format.

Decode the incoming `Base64` string to `ByteArray`

```
val imageByteArray = Base64.decode(user.image, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Then load `imageByteArray` to the `Glide` as below.

```
Glide
   .with(this)
   .asBitmap()
   .load(imageByteArray)  // ==> Pass the ByteArray here  
   .into(nav_user_image)
```

**EDIT 1 : Updated Answer**

From your code I can see that, drawing to canvas code is placed outside the `addOnSuccessListener` from `snapshots`. But you are accessing the fields of `loggedInUser` before the completion of `addOnSuccessListener` where the data is assigned.

> `addOnSuccessListener` is `async` operation and will not be executed
> in sequence like you written in your existing code.

Move the following code inside the `addOnSuccessListener`.

```
canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,loggedInUser.image.toInt()), 0F, 0F, color)
canvas1.drawText("User Name!", 30F, 40F, color)
```

**Your existing code.**

```
 mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
                                    .document(FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserId())
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                                        loggedInUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!
                                    }
                            canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,loggedInUser.image.toInt()), 0F, 0F, color)
                            canvas1.drawText("User Name!", 30F, 40F, color)
```

**Updated Answer 2 :**

Based on the error log, the image is retrieved as an remote url which can be directly loaded in the `ImageView`. But when you are trying to draw it in the `canvas` you need to decode the file from the remote url as `stream` and then set it in the `Canvas`.

Something like below

```
URL url = new URL(<PASS YOUR URL from FIREBASE>);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 ....
Bitmap receivedImageasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection .getInputStream());
.. 
canvas1.drawBitmap(receivedImageasBitmap)
```

Comment: I tried it. I am not using Glide because i want to draw that image on the canvas so when i tried your solution, It said Found "ByteArray" Required "Int" in this line of code.
                                        `canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,imageByteArray), 0F, 0F, color)`

Comment: Check my updated answer and let know if that works ! @perpetualdarkness

Comment: Hey, i tried your code and the app crashed. I updated my question with the error i got in the logcat.

Comment: Check my Updated Answer 2 @perpetualdarkness

Comment: tried it. got an error again. please check the updated question

Comment: You need to perform network operations in separate thread not in main thread. Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection

Comment: Thank you, it worked. although i have some other difficulties like the image is zoomed in the canvas and the image doesn't load unless the location is changed atleast once. would you like to help me with my app? This is the discussion [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234658/discussion-between-perpetualdarkness-and-hascher) if you want to help. Thanks!